# Who is the "on" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Can you please tell me the role of "on" in this sentence? Who is this "on"? We, they, I, etc.

> On n'en finirait pas de raconter ses aventures.

I don't have any more context, it's a sentence taken from a dictionary.

Comment: Without more context, please consult a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The word "on" includes *I* and *other people*, therefore, in English, it would be "we".

Like with "we", there are two main meanings:

- A small group of people

> *Mes amis et moi sommes allés au bois. On y a fait la fête.*

- A people, such as the French population at large

> *On est dans de beaux draps. La guerre a commencée.*

Answer (score 2):

*On* is a generic pronoun here, it doesn't represent anyone in particular. You can use the passive voice to avoid translating it:

> *Ses aventures n'en finiraient pas d'être racontées.*
> His/her adventures would never cease to be told.

Comment: Or you could translate it as *we*, *they*, or *people* — "we/they/people would never stop telling the story of his adventures."

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, especially *people*  which is necessarily generic unlike *we* and *they* that are still a bit ambiguous.

Comment: But even though it seems less likely, couldn't the French actually mean a specific *we* or a specific *they*, depending on context?

Comment: @PeterShor It could be indeed a specific *we*, definitely as *on* has replaced *nous* in spoken French but a *they* is still very likely to be a generic one.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents without any context.

> On n'en finirait pas de raconter ses aventures.

> We would never stop telling his/her/its/their adventures.

or

> They would never stop telling his/her/its/their adventures.

or

> People would never stop telling his/her/its/their adventures.

Personally, I prefer (a little dated/very formal though)

> One would never stop telling his/her/its/their adventures.

Comment: Are you sure the first sentence (*Ses aventures...*) is the one you wanted to quote?

Comment: @jlliagre Ooops:-)! You are right! Fixed already. Thanks a lot. I appreciate it!

Comment: Tu as de la chance que je ne t'ai pas poursuivi pour plagiat, ça aurait terni ta carrière ;-)